# Why Google glass WiFi network is missing some data in UDP connection?

Tags: udp, wifi, google-glass

I am connected using UDP network connection, When I receive data from broadcast listener missing some data. Is this the problem with wireless network, anyone experience similar or other network problem with own apps?

Comment: can you add your code, i will try helping you

Answer (score 2):

UDP connections don't offer sufficient error checking, especially over WiFi. Is there anyway you could use a TCP connection to suffice due to the fact that TCP will do error checking and request missing data?